# iOS: Notifications and navigation

Tags: ios

I have the following structure `AllTasks -> ConcreteTask -> SubTask`. I use `UINavigationController` , user always may understand her currenct location: i.e. on `ConcreteTask` screen she has `back` button that takes her to `AllTasks` screen.

Say, `Task1` is opened, and my app obtains new data for Task # 42. It displays alert (`UIAlertController`) saying "There is update for Task # 42. Do you want to open it?". User clicks "yes", and my app should open `Task42` screen.

What should I do with my navigation in this case?

*Idea 1:*

Add `Task42` to my navigation stack and open it.

So, navigation would be `AllTasks -> Task1 -->Task42`.  When user click `back` button, app will open `Task1` page.

I dislike this idea because it breaks navigation and confuses user. Instead of tree, we now have mess. What if user close my app and open it next day? She will see `Task42` page with `back` button that takes her to some random task!

*Idea 2*
Drain navigation stack to `AllTasks` and then open `Task42`.

So, navigation would be `AllTasks -->Task42`. When user click back button, app will open `AllTasks` page. No more mess.

But I dislike this idea because it is not easy for user to go back to `Task1`. She probably spent some time reading `Task1` and now my app simply closed it.

Does there is a beautiful way to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

The second idea you propose makes the most sense out of the two. Since the user is warned of the udpate and asked to choose between taking action or resuming to the current task, it does not seem damaging to position directly into the new task. Don't forget that **quality animation** are required for the user to keep a sense of hierarchy and positioning while the transition is happening.

However, I question the use of an **alert** in the first place. Alerts are disruptive and blocking, impeding user progress. As mentionned in the [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Alerts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW2), alerts should be used cautiously. The presented table discusses alternatives: depending on the criticality of the incoming udpate, other options should be considered.

#### Banner notification

[image: banner notification]

A banner notification has several advantages:

- the notification is less disruptive than an alert and does not block the user from his/her current task,
- when a notification appears, the user has three possibilities:

  - tap on the notification and directly jump to the concerned task,
  - extend the notification to see more detail, perhaps in this case a summary of the update,
  - dismiss the notification by swiping it up.

With this solution, you get to let the user decide without obstructing his/her way. This allows for the acknowledgement of the new information (as described in your *idea 1*) without messing with the structure and positioning (as described in your *idea 2*).

Comment: Thank you. But what if message interrupted user when she was typing some text? Looks like I need to save draft in this case. I agree about banners and alerts, and this is how iOS manages notifications when my app is in background, but when it is in foreground, I need to display message myself somehow. There is no official way to do that, so people do something like https://github.com/avielg/AGPushNote .